# Orientation at the boundary for manifold with corners: the simplex

Tags: differential-geometry, orientation

Consider the $n$-simplex $$\Delta[n]:=\{(t_{1},\dots,t_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\: : \: 0\leq t_{1}\leq t_{2}\leq  \dots \leq t_{n}\leq 1\}.$$ This is a manifold with corners. The cofaces map $d^{i}\: : \: \Delta[n-1]\to \Delta[n]$,  $i=0,\dots,n $, are defined via
$$
d^{0}(s_{1},\dots s_{n-1}):=(0,s_{1},\dots s_{n-1}),\quad d^{n}(s_{1},\dots s_{n-1}):=(s_{1},\dots s_{n-1},1)
$$
and
$$
d^{i}(s_{1},\dots s_{n-1}):=(0,s_{1},\dots, s_{i-1}, s_{i},s_{i}, s_{i+1}\dots , s_{n-1}),\:\text{ for }i=1,\dots n-1.
$$
The union of the image of these maps is the boundary of the $n$-simplex. For which $i$ are these inclusions orientation persevering?
I think that the answer should be: $d^{i}$ for $i$ odd or $i=n$, but i don't know how to prove that.